# issues saving data into csv during webscraping

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having some issues while saving rows in a csv file after web scraping. I used the same notation and it worked well before on another site but now the csv file is blank. It seems python is not writing any row.

I show you my code, thanks in advance:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import lxml

html_page = requests.get('https://www.scrapethissite.com/pages/forms/?page_num=1').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'lxml')

# get the number of pages (it might change in the future as the data is updated)
pagenum = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'pagination'})
n = pagenum.findAll('li')[-2].find('a')['href'].split('=')[1]

# now we convert the value of the page in a range so that we can loop over it
page = range(1, int(n) + 1)
print(page)

with open('HockeyLeague.csv', 'w') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    csv_writer.writerow(['team_name', 'year', 'wins', 'losses', 'win_perc', 'goal_for', 'goal_against'])

    for p in page:
        html_page = requests.get(f'https://www.scrapethissite.com/pages/forms/?page_num={p}&per_page=25').text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'lxml')

        table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'table'})

        for row in table.findAll('tr', {'class': 'team'}):

            # getting the wanted variables:
            team_name = row.find('td', {'class': 'name'}).text
            year = row.find('td', {'class': 'year'}).text
            wins = row.find('td', {'class': 'wins'}).text
            losses = row.find('td', {'class': 'losses'}).text
            goal_for = row.find('td', {'gf'}).text
            goal_against = row.find('td', {'ga'}).text

            try:
                win_perc = row.find('td', {'pct text-success'}).text
            except:
                win_perc = row.find('td', {'pct text-danger'}).text

            # write the data in the csv file we created at the beginning
            csv_writer.writerow([team_name, year, wins, losses, win_perc, goal_for, goal_against])
```

Comment: Hi @ele, try replacing `BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'lxml')` with `BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')`. Also, make sure you "sanitise" your output (e.g., remove '\n' and ' ') because the output I'm getting is weird. It's a bit like: `['\n                            Boston Bruins\n                        ', '\n                            1990\n                        ', '\n                            44\n                        ', '\n
  24\n                        ', '\n                            0.55\n                        ', ...]`

Comment: @ele Script is working in general, content is scraped and written to csv, could be optimized but written. At first check (print) your responses, do you get the expected data?

Comment: @AnonyMous stripping is a good idea, but why should the parser  be switched - is there any reason, that changes the behavior of writing csv?

Comment: @HedgeHog Oh no, It's more personal preference and in my experience it's slightly easier for beginners, just in terms of I guess usability?

Comment: @AnonyMous - Ah, for personal preference, okay. Just to clarify, there is no big difference in handling for valid HTML, advantage of `html.parser` it is built-in - so no extra dependencies needed, while `lxml` is the standard parser for `beautifulsoup` and very fast, lenient but needs dependency -> [more details from docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause script in general is working these are just some things you should keep in mind:

- I would recommend opening the file with `newline=''` on all platforms
  to disable universal newlines translation and `encoding='utf-8'` to
  be sure you are working on the "correct" one:

  ```
  with open('HockeyLeague.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
      ...
  ```
- `.strip()` your texts or use `.get_text(strip=True)` to get a clean
  output and avoid  linebreaks you do not wont.

  ```
  team_name = row.find('td', {'class': 'name'}).text.strip()
  year = row.find('td', {'class': 'year'}).text.strip() 
  ...
  ```
- In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` -
  For more take a minute to [check
  docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)

###### Alternative Example

Uses a while loop the checks the "Next Button" and extract its url, also `stripped_strings` to extract the texts from each row:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = 'https://www.scrapethissite.com/pages/forms/'

with open('HockeyLeague.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f)
    csv_writer.writerow(['team_name', 'year', 'wins', 'losses', 'win_perc', 'goal_for', 'goal_against'])

    while True:
        html_page = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)

        for row in soup.find_all('tr', {'class': 'team'}):
            # write the data in the csv file we created at the beginning 
            csv_writer.writerow(list(row.stripped_strings)[:-1])

        if soup.select_one('.pagination a[aria-label="Next"]'):
            url = 'https://www.scrapethissite.com'+soup.select_one('.pagination a[aria-label="Next"]').get('href')
        else:
            break
```

###### Output

```
team_name,year,wins,losses,win_perc,goal_for,goal_against
Boston Bruins,1990,44,24,0.55,299,264
Buffalo Sabres,1990,31,30,0.388,292,278
Calgary Flames,1990,46,26,0.575,344,263
Chicago Blackhawks,1990,49,23,0.613,284,211
Detroit Red Wings,1990,34,38,0.425,273,298
Edmonton Oilers,1990,37,37,0.463,272,272
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! By adding your suggestions the code runs correctly. Thanks for the advice!